# What could be the range of score in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the maximum  range of score I could get in Elasticsearch
For example:

```
 {
        "_index": "customer_documents",
        "_type": "payslips",
        "_id": "49412",
        "_score": 1,
 }
```

I am asking about this `_score:` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the top of score is undefined. The only limitation in the docs is "positive float number", so minimum is 0 and there is not maximum value.

This way there is always enough range to differentiate between documents.

Comment: Can you explain this(This way there is always enough range to differentiate between documents)   clearly .Thanks

Comment: If you have a Range for scoring between 0 and 1 and indexed 1.000.000 documents, which all match your query, also you want to boost certain properties, it will become very hard to differentiate which document matched best. This is worst-case scenario and probably not the real reason. Over the last days i learnt that it is possible to configure scoring totally like you want. Look for function-score in the references.